# Question about complement of frequency? (Using 过 and 次)

Tags: grammar

I know that it is grammatical to say "我游了三次泳."

If I wanted to say, "I saw you three times," could I say it as "我看过你三次见"?

Thank you,
Rachel

Comment: doubtful, 我看见过你三次  would be correct

Comment: No. I don't know the exact reason but I guess whether you can break a two-character verb like 游了三次泳 depends on the formation of the verb. For two-character verbs constructed by "verb+noun" it's fine, such as 游泳，打架，吃惊，睡觉. But 看见 is "verb+verb" so breaking it like that is wrong.

Comment: 我看了你三眼 is the analogous form here.

Comment: although iciba，e。g。，classifies 泳 as 动词，it seems to be always treated as noun, at least in the combination 游泳，on the other hand 见 in 看见 functions as complement of result (similar to 到）

Comment: 游了三次泳 seems somewhat hard to compare with 看了三眼 b／c  三次 is inserted between V and N of
the 离合词 VN, which is standard, on the other hand 看 is a one-syllable verb, and 眼 functions as（borrowed) verbal measure word,（借用）动量词, it can be combined with other verbs besides 看，e.g.瞥、瞧, also  看一眼 seems very common and 看两眼 still is, but iciba句库 e.g. has no example for 看三眼 (neither has jukuu)

Comment: ＂现代汉语离合词用法词典＂containing ４０６６＂离合词＂includes ＂看见＂，－＞ there are different types of ＂离合词＂(in the wide sense):看见：看而有结果，即看到。［离］（１）＂看＂与＂见＂之间加＂得＂，表示可能：黑板上的字你看得见吗？屋子里的东西我都看得见（２）＂看＂与＂见＂之间加＂不＂，表示不可能：屋外漆黑一片，我什么都看不见。／大雁飞得很快，一眨眼就看不见了。［合］合任谓语：你看见那幅世界名画了吗？（２）合带＂了＂、＂过＂等助词：林老师呢？你看见了吗？／峨眉山的金顶日出你看见过吗？（３）合带宾语：站在窗口，可以看见大海。（４）合带状语：我刚才在图书馆看见新来的校长了。（５）合带补语：这种大鲨鱼我只看见过一次！！！！！！！［误］你刚才看见没有苏珊？［正］（１）你刚才看见苏珊没有？（２）你刚才看没看见苏珊？（３）你刚才看见苏珊了吗？

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

The first sentence: 游 is a verb. 泳 is a noun.

The second sentence: 看 is a verb. 見 is an adverb. It is not the same structure as the first one.

You should just say 我看過你三次 or 我見過你三次.

Comment: No, [`泳`](http://www.zdic.net/z/1c/xs/6CF3.htm) is a verb.

Comment: You can't just look at one word. It's very normal in Chinese to change a word's type in a sentence. It's called "轉品." When you say "游了三次泳," 泳 becomes a noun.

Comment: So `游` is a verb, `泳` is a verb, and `游泳` become verb + noun here. And then `看` is a verb, `见` is a verb, but `看见` doesn't become verb + noun. Why? What's the difference? That's the point what OP is asking.

Comment: So why `看見` can't be verb + noun? Because that's not what people mean. If it was verb + noun, then `見` became an object, saw by someone. Weird, right? So I guess you have to always understand each word's meaning in a sentence to determine.

Comment: `泳` becomes an object being "swam" is weird too. What does it mean? The swimming pool? Anyway, to conclude your opinion, it depends on context, no rules here.

Comment: I agree it's weird, although people accept it. The reason is that it's two verbs. It's like "I am doing swimming." Weird but acceptable. 看見 is verb + adverb, so it's not acceptable to make 見 a nown.

Comment: It's better to just say "我游泳了三次" or "我游了三次."

Comment: Take a swim, go for a swim.

Answer (score -1):

When a verb has an object, the verb has to be repeated before a time/frequency complement. In this case, this would result in

我見過你見過三次。

Another way to handle objects and complements is to prepone the object:

你人我見過三次。

In 我游了三次泳, the word 游泳 is a loose verb-object pair that should be viewed as just a verb.  The 泳 is difficult to explain as an object in many grammatical constructions.

Comment: Not true. You should just say 我見過你三次. See my answer below.